# how to change the background colour of entire body except a sidebar div

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I overlay and dim screen, after click on a menu button?

```
<ul id="gn-menu" class="gn-menu-main">
                <li class="gn-trigger">
                    <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
                    <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
                        <div class="gn-scroller">
                            <ul class="gn-menu">
                                <li class="gn-search-item">
                                    <input placeholder="Search" type="search" class="gn-search">
                                    <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search"><span>Search</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-download">Downloads</a>
                                    <ul class="gn-submenu">
                                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-illustrator">Vector Illustrations</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-photoshop">Photoshop files</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-cog">Settings</a></li>
                                <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-help">Help</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-archive">Archives</a>
                                    <ul class="gn-submenu">
                                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-article">Articles</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-pictures">Images</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="gn-icon gn-icon-videos">Videos</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
                    </nav>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops">Codrops</a></li>
                <li><a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-prev" href="http://tympanus.net/Development/HeaderEffects/"><span>Previous Demo</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-drop" href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=16030"><span>Back to the Codrops Article</span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

**User clicks on here(a button)**
[image]

**Sidebar opens on right( here I wanted to make the entire screen with   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9); except right sidebar)**

[image]

Any tips or help will be highly appropriated, ui kind of work is very complex in my scenario, i am Java developer, creating my personal site.. i have learnt css & jquery too as beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `box-shadow: inset -9999px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);` on the `header` element.

Another way is to change the `background-color` of the `header` element.

The last way is to use a huge `div` that covers over the page. Set the menu to have a higher `z-index` than the huge `div`.

These styles should be applied to the huge `div`:

```
z-index: 100;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

And these styles to the Nexus Menu:

```
z-index: 1000;
position: /* Anything but static */
```

Comment: Hi i tried the first one but no output... `<div class="navbar-header" style="box-shadow: inset -9999px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">`

Comment: I meant to put the `box-shadow` on the `header` tag.

Comment: Hi I applied but its showing like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1E4Nj.jpg   ,Can you  briefly tell me about the 3rd way as you described in your above sentences..

Comment: thanks, it works. Just wondering can we block the dim `div` also, so that user can not links on page if sidebar opened

Comment: I tried in this way but its blocking entire page!     $(".overlay").not(".rt-menu-main").disable();  , where `.rt-menu-main` is sidebar div

Comment: To not click links on the page, put `pointer-events: none` to the `div`. To not block the entire page, make sure the `.rt-menu-main` is not `position: static`, and make it a very high `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading , utilizing `jQuery`

```
$(function() {
  // create toggle flag
  var clicked = false;
  // cache `header` `css`
  var bg = $("header").css(["background", "opacity", "width"]);
  $("a.gn-icon").on("click", function() {
    if (clicked === false) {
      // set dimmed screen
      $("header").css({"background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)"
                      , "opacity":"0.25"
                        // `355`: `.gn-menu` `width`
                      , "width":window.innerWidth - 355
                      , "float":"right"});
      // reset `clicked` flag
      clicked = true;
    } else {
      // reset `header` `css` to initial
      $("header").css(bg);
      // reset `clicked` flag
      clicked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Donkey Note, `jQuery` not appear loaded, defined at linked page ? Tried `js` at post after first at `console` , `var script = document.createElement("script"); script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"; document.body.appendChild(script);`

Comment: Thanks, But not covering entire page(except sidebar)  , I applied as you suggested , output>>: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1E4Nj.jpg  , problem not covering entire page

Comment: @Donkey Tried at `console` at linked page; appeared to cover entire page except for top portion of navigation at "CODROPS" , "PREVIOUS DEMO" links. May require some adjustments to `width` of `header` . Difficult to determine issues with only viewing image of results. Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?